# Importing CSV numbers formatted as string into ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv

I'm importing a .csv that contains data that I am joining to a shapefile. The value that I am joining is shown in the first column of the image below. When I import the data into ArcMap the data in the second column is converted to type 'string' instead of 'integer'.

How do I import the data so that numeric values are of type integer 'instead' of 'string'?

[image]

Comment: [This tutorial](https://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/) has a solution for QGIS that I think would also work for ArcMap. Basically you add a line to the CSV file that defines the column types. Or you may find these questions helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109461/changing-field-type-of-excel-attribute-table-for-a-join, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78087/problem-in-using-schema-ini-to-force-arcmap-recognize-field-types

Comment: How do you import it?

Comment: `schema.ini` https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164973/2856 https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/30670/2856 http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/adding-an-ascii-or-text-file-table.htm#GUID-9131A09B-6C15-4654-8A72-F01C0C271392

Comment: A simple workaround is to let them be imported as strings and then add a new integer field (Add Field).  Use Field Calculator to reproduce the old values into the new field, where they will show up as integers.

Comment: Precisely how did you import it when you got your undesirable result?